# Child Component to Parent Component Communication without a Children Nested in a Template in Angular (Angular 2+)

Tags: angularjs, angular

Every answered post, and every tutorial shows that the `EventEmitter()` can be used for a child component to talk to it's parent if the parent is listening; however, *that only works if the child component is part of the parent's template*; otherwise, the emit can only be picked up by the app's root component.

Here's a simple structure (using `<ng-content></ng-content>` on the `radio-group` to transclude the children):

```
<radio-group>
  <radio></radio>
  <radio></radio>
  <radio></radio>
</radio-group>
```

When a custom radio component gets checked, it should emit an event--that works great.  But the custom radio group won't hear the event even if it's listening because it's children are not part of it's template in this implementation.

I don't understand how [Angular Material 2 Radios](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/radio) pull this off; but they'd be a good reference for someone who understands Angular 2 well.

Click on the "Examples" tab of [Angular's Material 2 Radio Demo](https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio) to see what I'm trying to accomplish, and the source button to see the same structure I'm trying to duplicate.

Again, I'm not trying to copy and paste their implementation, I'm trying to get the child components to communicate events to a parent component when the child components are not part of the parent's template.

Comment: _the emit can only be picked up by the app's root component_ - where did  you read that? AFAIK, custom events don't bubble to the root compoennt

Comment: also, the example that you linked to uses `ngModel` on `<radio-group>` and that's how they update a property on the wrapping component

Comment: @Maximus You're right, custom events don't bubble up, but in my example, it skips all wrapping components and goes to the root component since that is technically the scope.  I'll checkout the ngModel again in that context--it's just quite complicated in there.

Comment: it's not complicated, maybe you're overthinking this, `<md-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">`, `favoriteSeason` is defined on the root `RadioNgModelExample`, check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [that plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dpqdPAeas2hFBfs1DrIh?p=preview) you'll see that they have the following structure:

```
<radio-ng-model-example>
    <md-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
        <md-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
            {{season}}
        </md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
    <div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
</radio-ng-model-example>
```

With `radio-ng-model-example` being the root component. So they use `EventEmitter` to communicate between `md-radio-button` and `md-radio-group`, and `ngModel` to communicate between `md-radio-group` and `radio-ng-model-example`.

Comment: The ngModel approach addressed my question; however, in my implementation where the radio group and radios are not part of the same file, I had to add a parent reference to the radios to access the model methods on the parent group. `constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => RadioGroupComponent)) private radioGroup:RadioGroupComponent) {}`

Answer (score 1):

When child components are not part of the parent's template, they are basically content children. And they are scoped within Parent component.

So for example, if you have a component named `my-component` and in its template you have something like below,

```
<parent [input]='somevar1' (output)='somemethod1()' >
   <child [input]='somevar2' (output)='somemethod2()' ></child>
</parent>
```

`somevar1`,`somevar2`,`somemethod1`,`somemethod2` comes from scope of `my-component`.

Based upon this understanding it is pretty safe to say that the `parent` and `child` can be treated as siblings within the scope of `my-component`. So you can communicate between these two using `my-component` scope.

Example,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `<h1>Parent</h1>
  {{awesomeInput}}
  <hr />
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent { 
   @Input() awesomeInput: string;
}
```

Child component,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<h1>Child</h1>
  <button (click)='sendAwesomeOutput()'>Click me!!</button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() awesomeOutput =  new EventEmitter();

  sendAwesomeOutput(){
    this.awesomeOutput.next('awesome output from child!!');
  }
}
```

Component in which above components are used in template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <hr />
  <parent [awesomeInput]="defaultInput" >
     <child (awesomeOutput)="getOutputFromChild($event)" ></child>
  </parent>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular';
  defaultInput = 'default value for parent';

  getOutputFromChild(val){
    this.defaultInput = val;
  }
}
```

**Update**

You may be little creative how you are passing values between parent-Child, and can totally do in template itself.  Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DE2mFmCIQYFJQ9lYf92L?p=preview)!!

```
<parent awesomeInput="{{child1.awesomeOutput | async }}" >
     <child #child1 ></child>
</parent>
```

The one above considers scenarios if you have to process anything.

Check out this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ygfQC879AbtUIEfHegqt?p=preview)!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Your explanation was fantastic and made a lot of sense; only in this case, I don't want an additional wrapper to pull it off, so the radio-group and radios can be independent.  I think the ngModel seems to be the best solution for the communication I need.

Comment: when you use `[(ngModel)]="somevar"` that is also using scope of the wrapper\component where you are using it. Try using somevar in the component where you are defining this like {{somevar}}, Having said that you can be creative and use some shortcuts to bind directly `"without"` involving parent  <parent awesomeInput="{{child1.awesomeOutput | async }}" >
     <child #child1  ></child>
  </parent>, Cheers!!

Comment: Thank for all those other approaches, they are still very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the title question without using ngModel, bindings, or EventEmitter (since it doesn't work outside of a template), and flexible enough to have any kind of content in each child component, in Angular 2.4, here's another approach for other implementations:

**Example:**
"Presenters" at a council of Odin (the "Organizer"). Only one presenter can talk (appear) at a time. Who ever presents next, signals to the organizer their intent, and the organizer stops the other presenters from speaking so the new presenter can resume their presentation.

(Demo screenshot minus additional nested content:)
[image: Demo screenshot minus additional nested content]
Clicking any button causes all the presenters to hide but the one you just clicked.

**Usage:**

```
<organizer>
    <presenter>
        <h2>Thor</h2>
        <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt ea nisi impedit aspernatur sint voluptatum odit aperiam, soluta, explicabo, nesciunt earum quo. Vel quod, ratione ullam deserunt commodi quaerat fugiat!</summary>
        <asgardian-power-point></asgardian-power-point>
    </presenter>
    <presenter>
        <h2>Loki</h2>
        <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt ea nisi impedit aspernatur sint voluptatum odit aperiam, soluta, explicabo, nesciunt earum quo. Vel quod, ratione ullam deserunt commodi quaerat fugiat!</summary>
        <interjection></interjection>
        <lies></lies>
    </presenter>
    <presenter>
        <h2>Sif</h2>
        <summary>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt ea nisi impedit aspernatur sint voluptatum odit aperiam, soluta, explicabo, nesciunt earum quo. Vel quod, ratione ullam deserunt commodi quaerat fugiat!</summary>
        <asgardian-power-point></asgardian-power-point>
    </presenter>
</organizer>
```

**organizer.component.html:**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**organizer.component.ts:**

```
import {
    Component,
    ContentChildren,
    QueryList
} from '@angular/core';

import { PresenterComponent } from '../presenter/presenter.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'organizer',
    templateUrl: './organizer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./organizer.component.scss']
})

export class OrganizerComponent {

    @ContentChildren(PresenterComponent) presenters: QueryList<PresenterComponent>;

    stopPresenters() {
        this.presenters.forEach(function(item) {
            item.conclude();
        });
    }

}
```

**presenter.component.html:**

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;" [style.height]="expand ? 'auto' : '30px'">
    <button (click)="present()">Present</button>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**presenter.component.ts:**

```
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    Inject,
    forwardRef
} from '@angular/core';

import { OrganizerComponent } from '../organizer/organizer.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'presenter',
    templateUrl: './presenter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./presenter.component.scss']
})

export class PresenterComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => OrganizerComponent)) private organizer:OrganizerComponent) {}

    @Input() expand: boolean = false;

    present() {
        this.organizer.stopPresenters();
        this.expand = true;
    }

    conclude() {
        this.expand = false;
    }

}
```